# Hashing MAC addresses Java/Android

Tags: java, android, security, encryption, hash

I want to scan nearby wifi routers and store their mac addresses in a secure manner such that the original mac addresses cannot be reconstructed (or be infeasible to do so). The mac addresses are represented as strings with the form xx:xx:xx:xx:x:xx where x is a digit or a letter.

Every time I find the same mac address it should be mapped to the same output string but any two different mac addresses should produce different outputs. I have read that MD5 algorithm is used to hash passwords. Would it be a good idea to use MD5, or should I consider other algorithms?. I would not be a big problem if there are some collisions.

After I have collected all the mac addresses (no new ones will be added) I am thinking in replacing each hashed value with a single integer 1...n where n is the total number of distinct mac addresses.

I want to implement this in Android.

Comment: Yes, you may consider hash function like MD5. If the MAC addresses are super-hyper-government-confidential, use something stronger (like SHA-512).

Comment: Your use case is not significantly different from passphrases: you want to store a hashed edition of the passphrase in the database, not the plaintext passphrase, so if the database gets stolen, nobody can get to the plaintext passphrases. There is a *lot* written about how to properly store passphrases in a database. Using a hash algorithm (e.g., MD5) is a starting point but usually insufficient. However, I have no idea how secure you need this to be.

Answer (score 0):

Hashing is not a perfect solution for this problem. If there is enough computing power, then one can try hashing all the possible MAC addresses. It is feasible to do so today. It all depends on how important these MAC addresses are. Maybe you should apply hash algo 10^5 times, to make hash computation slower (it is a usual trick for passwords)

A better solution is to encrypt the addresses with good encryption (AES, etc.)

If you still want to use hashing, use a current one instead of MD5, like SHA-3.

Comment: If slowing down the hash computation is the need then use a password hashing method such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions.

Answer (score 0):

MD5 is a common hashing algorithm with a very low probability that different MAC addresses will produce the same hash value ie. hash collision.
MAC addresses in general are unique as they are built in identifiers of hardware network devices. This unique characteristic can also maintain the the avoidance of hash collision. In the case that multiple devices have the same MAC adresses ie. MAC spoofing you might want to consider concatenating the hash with a random salt before generating the hash. MD5 will serve the purpose of a producing a unique hash but if your application requires countermeasures to dictionary attacks, using tools such as Hashcat and John the Ripper- for finding plaintext MAC adresses from hashes- consider using a more secure hashing algorithm like SHA-256. It also has a lower hash collision rate.

Answer (score 0):

### Passwords

**For password** it is not enough to just use one-way-hashes like **MD5** or **SHA-256** as this is quite vulnerable to [rainbow tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table). Also, brute force trying out all combinations of valid passwords are often fast enough to cause problem.

**With passwords**, the usual way to **counter rainbow tables** are by adding a **random salt** to the calculation preventing pre-calculated tables. And to **counter brute force**, the method used is to do **many iterations** with a one-way-hash to make the **process slower**. Well tested methods exists for this like [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) or [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) etc.

### Mac Address to Unique ID

**In your case you want:**

1. Same MAC always map to same ID
2. ID should be constructed in a secure manner such that the original MAC addresses cannot be reconstructed

Here 1) is basically a property that the password algorithms try to prevent, by adding the salt.

With 2) we should prevent brute force to work.

A standard [MAC Address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) have space for 48 bit's of information. These bits are then sometimes sub divided into vendor assigned ranges. A specific vendor might only have 24 bit's for there MAC's. With such a small space, brute forcing all combinations for that vendor is certainly possible, even with the slow algorithms mentioned above for passwords.

**Basically**, you need something secret in the process to prevent brute force. This could e.g. be introduce by encryption - A possible methode could be:

```
 MAC_ID = BASE_64_ENCODE(AES_ENCRYPT(MD5(MAC), SECRET_KEY))
```